# Can't launch Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, shared-library

I'm unable to launch Nautilus. 
If I launch it from a Terminal, it says:

```
    nautilus: error while loading shared libraries: libunity-protocol-private.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I LD_PRELOAD this lib, this does work, but I want the solution to be permanent.
Does someone has a clue to that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed !

I encountered many problems with unity, so I typed

```
    sudo unity --distro
```

And it solved all my problems.

Thanks anyway!

Edit: The unity usage says to run this option as a sudo, that's why I did it

Comment: Because I read the usage:

unity --help

Comment: Right then. Upvoted the answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

See if re-installing will re-configure Nautilus to work correctly:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall libunity will fix your problem

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libunity9
```

Comment: I tried this, still the same problem...